# WCF call from .Net Standard Library passing null

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I have a .Net Standard library that calls a simple WCF service using the Microsoft WCF Webservice reference provider. I´m just calling a login method passing 3 strings and receiving an integer. This is the sample code for the call.

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(Constants.SoapUrl);
Twsvc.twsSoapClient client = new Twsvc.twsSoapClient(binding, address);
var i = await client.LoginAsync("admin", "wms", "baguer");
```

If a call the method from a windows forms application it works Ok, BUT.. from a Xamarin Forms application i have this error

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an obj..

After trying to find the cause i discover on a trace that the stored procedure that the service is calling id being call with null parameters.. this is the result from the trace

exec LoginUser @Usuario=NULL,@Clave=NULL,@Identificador=NULL

This is the calling code from the generated reference

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> LoginAsync(string Usuario, string Clave, string Identificador)
    {
        return base.Channel.LoginAsync(Usuario, Clave, Identificador);
    }
```

I have no idea of the reason of this behavior, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this post pertains to  server error. Yet you provided us with the code from the client. I don't see any way to debug this with the information given.

Comment: The service is not the problem, it works as expected when the call is made from the windows forms client (exactly the same call, using the same library referenced in the project). The problem only occurs when the call is made from a Xamarin Forms application.

Comment: I don't know what "problem" means in this context. The server is the one passing the null values to the stored procedure. It may contain logic (either correct or incorrect) that is sensitive the particulars of the client (e.g. it might white list the client IP, check the user agent, have bot detection logic-- anything, really). So you need to know what the server is doing to know why the change in client had an effect.

Comment: The problem is that the WCF is receiving nulls in every parameter sent by the xamarin forms application BUT.. works ok when the call is made from a winforms application.

Comment: Have you confirmed that WCF is receiving nulls? Seems to me you have only confirmed that SQL is receiving nulls. Perhaps you could look at a Fiddler trace or web logs to confirm what is contained in the traffic.

Comment: If you are asking why your service is receiving nulls, there we simply cant answer, there is too many other variables, one of which is that you have sufficiently proven to us that the service is receiving nulls. if it is, you need to create a minimal reproducible example, and show us the service code, the client code, and the proxy code so we can begin to help